# What is the amplitude factor means?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

There is a localized particle in a volume $V_0$, and we prepare a wave packet. It is written with eigenstates $ \chi_{a,q} $ as below.
$$
X_{a,p}=\int a({\bf q}-{\bf p})\frac{e^{i{\bf q}\cdot r}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}g_a d^3q
$$
$$
= \int a({\bf q}-{\bf p}) \chi_{a,q}d^3q
$$
${\bf q}$ corresponds to cordinate and ${\bf p}$ corresponds to momentum.
I can not understad why the amplitude paramerter is written as $a({\bf q}-{\bf p})$?
What is the phisical meaning? The dimentions does not correspond.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{q}$ and $\textbf{p}$ both have the dimension of momentum in the equation.

The equation is the Fourier expansion of the wavepacket with momentum $\textbf{p}$. $a(\textbf{q}-\textbf{p})$ is the usual Fourier coefficient.